# replay tweet from google script

Tags: javascript, twitter, google-apps-script

I used this library for Google script :
https://script.google.com/macros/library/d/MKvHYYdYA4G5JJHj7hxIcoh8V4oX7X1M_/7

But i have problem with replay tweet 
he is sent tweet but not replay 
i am post id_str but still not replay

```
    var user = tweets[i].user.screen_name;
    var reply_id = tweets[i].id_str;
    var tweet = "@" + usser + " \nHello World!";
    twit.sendTweet(tweet, reply_id);
```

Comment: Possible typo ? **usser**

Comment: How replace string type to object

Comment: THX IT WORK                                                                                               twit.sendTweet(tweet, {in_reply_to_status_id:reply_id} );

Answer (score 1):

Solve is replace  reply_id from string to object:

```
twit.sendTweet(tweet, {in_reply_to_status_id:reply_id} );
```